# JSON.parse no longer working in jquery 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've got a js which is currently working with jquery 2.1.1 .. then I purchased a template that comes with jquery 3.1.1. Soon after I migrated the code to the template the js stops working particularly at JSON.parse .. I've searched that perhaps it's deprecated but it's not. Here's the code:

```
var login = $("#loginnow").ladda();

$(document).ready(function() {

    login.click(function(event) {
        login.ladda('start');
        if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#frSendMessage").submit();
        }
    });

    $("#resetpass").click(function(event) {
        swal({
            title: "Forgot Password",
            text: "Enter your email to proceed with Password Reset",
            type: "input",
            showCancelButton: true,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
            inputPlaceholder: "email"
        },
        function(inputValue) {
            var v_email = verifyVar(encodeURIComponent(inputValue),'resetpass');
            displayVerify(v_email);
        });
    });
});

function loginNow(username,password) {
    var data = 'username='+value+'&password='+type;
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        url: '/pgadm/ajax/login.php'
    });
}

function verifyVar(value,type) {
    var data = 'value='+value+'&type='+type;
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        url: '/pgadm/ajax/resetpass.php'
    });
}

function displayVerify(ajaxCall) {
    ajaxCall.success(function(realData) {
        response = JSON.parse(realData);
        alert(response)
        if (!response.success) {
            var returnmsg = response.message;
            swal({
                title: "Error",
                text: returnmsg,
                type: "error",
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonText: "Back",
                closeOnConfirm: true
            });
        } else {
            swal({
                title: "On Its Way!",
                text: "Please check your email for further instruction on how to reset your Password",
                type: "success",
                showCancelButton: false,
                confirmButtonText: "Okay",
                closeOnConfirm: true
            });         
        }
    });
}
```

Now, as you can see, the function displayVerify() breaks at JSON.parse. Firebug shows normal json reply from the server but it seems not being parsed by the script. Perhaps anyone have had such experience before?

Comment: JSON.parse is not a jquery method

Comment: Do a `console.log(realData)` before `JSON.parse()`

Comment: More than likely, your `realData` has already been parsed by JQuery.

Comment: if the server script sends `Content-type: application/json` then jQuery will automatically parse it.

Comment: @juvian He never said it was, just that it doesn't work in his script after changing jQuery versions.

Comment: Barmar, the server is sending text instead .. hence the parsing

Comment: Is the response from server is a valid JSON? Can you share the response text?

Comment: Pete .. here goes - {"success":false,"message":"Invalid email format"}